# How can I use 'map' in a function for filtering different attributes of an entity?

Tags: swift, core-data

For filtering search tokens in a CoreData application I use 'filter' and 'map' on an array of Entities. In the case of 'filter' I can use a NSPredicate with #keyPath. For 'map' it is necessary to define the attribute inside of the code. It is possible to write a general function (instead of searchNames, searchStreets, ...) where I can define the Entity and the Attribute as parameters?

```
class Person {
    @objc var name : String?
    @objc var city : String?
    @objc var street : String?
}

var personlist = [Person]()

func searchNames(_ searchText: String) -> [String?] {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K BEGINSWITH[c] %@", #keyPath(Person.name), searchText)
    let names = personlist.filter({ predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }).map { $0.name }
    return names
}

func searchStreets(_ searchText: String) -> [String?] {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K BEGINSWITH[c] %@", #keyPath(Person.street), searchText)
    let streets = personlist.filter({ predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }).map { $0.street }
    return streets
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit *hacky* because you have to convert the Swift `KeyPath` to a string with `NSExpression` but it's possible

```
func searchProperty<V>(_ keyPath : KeyPath<Person,V>, searchText: String) -> [V] {
    let keyPathString = NSExpression(forKeyPath: keyPath).keyPath
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K BEGINSWITH[c] %@", keyPathString, searchText)
    return personlist.filter({ predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }).compactMap{$0[keyPath: keyPath]}
}
```

As the properties are optional `comapctMap` is the better choice because it returns a non-optional array.

You can use it

```
let result = searchProperty(\.name, searchText: "A")
```

Consider that a class which does not inherit from `NSManageObject` must inherit from `NSObject` and mark the properties with `dynamic`

```
class Person : NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var name : String? ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works fine. The key issue is using `KeyPath<Person,V>` as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, but it's also the requirement to convert a Swift `KeyPath` to a String to be able to use it in `NSPredicate`.